# Hierarchical queries, is this example correct?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, hierarchical-query

I'm trying to understand this concept, but this example gives me a headache.
I'd expect that it should behave somehow similarly like resursion/mathematical induction. On every step you have a current value and a rule based on which you can calculate the next value.
So if you have a starting point `start with ename = 'BLAKE'` and `connect by prior empno = mgr` the resulting recursion should behave like the arrows i've painted on image, and not match every person to the starting point.
[image: SQL QUERY]

**Thanks a lot**

P.S. [article i'm refering to](https://www.highgo.ca/2021/04/09/how-to-run-hierarchical-queries-with-postgresql/)

Comment: how does `emp` look like?

Comment: referred some docs. [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm), [this](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-run-hierarchical-queries-oracle-and-postgresql), [this](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/oracle-to-postgresql-start-with-connect-by/) to understand its postgreSQL equivalents. Turns out it does not change how the table looks like.

Comment: but why all people refer directly to Blake Manager, why isn't it chained?

Comment: see `emp` table. Blake is indeed their manager according to the data. The hierarchical query did not update any records from the table - instead it creates a pseudocolumn `level` (along with other things). Check out the links I shared above.

Comment: so i can think about hierarchical queries as a BFS traversal of table with a root defined by `start with ...` and `connect by` as a way of defining which rows are a children node of parent = how edges connect verticies?

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong : if in the emp table there was a row which had a mgr=7499 (like empno of ALLEN salesman) the he would appear on the bottom of resulting table?

Comment: yes, you're right. however, not necessarily always at the very bottom

Comment: That's an Oracle query, so why the `postgresql` tag.

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Thanks @samkart, you've helped me a lot. When you say "not necessarily always at the very bottom " you mean that it can behave both like a BFS and DFS depending on our intention? Can we do then any tree traversal order, like A*?

Comment: not that I know of. the doc mentioned top-down only.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think that image is just a screengrab from the [article linked above](https://www.highgo.ca/2021/04/09/how-to-run-hierarchical-queries-with-postgresql/)